# Bind a new toggle button to an existing option group in MS ACCESS 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have an option group on a form (Ms Access 2007) wiht some toggle buttons on it.I now want to add another toggle button to that existing option group.After adding one I see that it is not bound to the option group and there is no such property as 'option value' for the new toggle button.
Please suggest how do I bind them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to add an option is to copy an existing option from the group. Just select an option button and copy and paste it. It will have an invalid value - in 2010 and possible 2007, you will be prompted to change the value. if you are not, you can change it on the data tab of the property sheet. You can also add an option within the option group frame, it will be added to the sequence. You will then have to size it to match.